# Does hardware programming depend on the command prompt window?

Tags: assembly, hardware

This question may seem a bit weird, but I could not resist asking, since I wasn't able to come to a logical conclusion.
We had to implement a BCD up-down counter on a Logic Controller Interface. The code that had been created, was right and the connections were good (The Logic Controller Interface, the systems and all components used were new).
We followed the procedure provided [here](http://www.codeshuffle.in/2016/05/2b-bcd-up-down-counter.html). On doing so, we exeuted the program to find no result.
After multiple attempts, we realized that the program executed, only when the command prompt was in fullscreen. This did not occur only for a particular program, but for all. Although I heard about it being a form of compatibility issue (which has not been emphasized on), it does not settle in as a logical answer.
Why does this occur ? Is it really a compatibility issue ? And if so, how ? The systems used were 32-bit systems with either windows xp or windows 7 basic, if it would help.

Comment: That is an interesting question that I would love to hear the answer for as well.  I guess it comes down to what language and therefore what kind of command prompt interface was used.

Comment: With that little information, it is hard to say what the problem is. Generally, whether the console window is fullscreen or not shouldn't matter.

Comment: I suspect that you directly talk to the hardware using `in` and `out` instructions. It is possible that Windows temporarily suspends certain drivers (e.g. the parallel port driver) when the command window is in fullscreen mode, but this is just speculation.

Comment: Makes me then think that there is a better way to code this using the Windows API more effectively?

Comment: @fuz I had the same speculation, but unfortunately it didn't sit quite right. Is there any other information that I could provide that might be of help ? (if possible)

Comment: @maheshRao I can perform further research but first I need more details about your problem. How do you talk to the controller? Can you show us your complete code?

Comment: Well we used the exact same code provided by the link in the question. We used MASM assembler to produce the .obj, if that could help ?

Comment: I'm new to the Logic Controller Interface component, can you elaborate on the hardware interface used? Particularly, are you connecting an external component to the PC? Using which bus/technology? The IO addresses shown in the code come from? Finally, you are making a 16-bit executable run in VM86 (WoW Windows technology)? Do Windows really allow a user mode program to do IO?

Comment: @Margaret Bloom  would [this](http://www.codeshuffle.in/2016/05/microprocessor-hardware-programming.html?m=1) help ?

Comment: The `allowio` program clarifies the part about IO permission I guess.

Comment: No hardware programming does not require a command prompt...used to be called giveio (I think from a DrDobbs article?) is it called allowio now?  can make kernel drivers in any OS that allow you to punch through/around the OS...